# Passing object in android

Tags: android

I have some question to you, because this is still not clear for me. So I have MainActivity, SecondActivity, ThirdActivity and a Player class. In SecondActivity and ThirdActivity i have Buy button, which should buy something and minus PlayerCash. But the Player object exist only in Main Activity. Some people told me to use serializable or parcelable to have access to Player object, but i have few question. What when Player go to second activity, buy something and click back button? Does Player "cash" change? I will have many activities and in every one i need have access to playerCash and want to change it whenever user click Buy button. Can someone tell me what technique should i use? Im stuck here for so long so any help would be nice. Thanks

Comment: Is the Player information saved in the locale database?

Comment: No because i dont know how to do this and what should i learn. Is local database solution for this what i want to do?

Comment: I need to know from where are you getting the how are you controlling it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to pass the Player information in the second and third class using `intent.putExtras("Key", "Value")` method. You can pass the whole Player object or you can just pass the required information (id, name etc) which depends on your situation.

If the Player information is saved in the locale database then you can update it in database in the second or third activity since you will have ID of Player.

Comment: No. From where are you getting the data for the Player? From the Server?

Comment: Im not sure about what u asking. Player object exist in MainActivity and all i want to do is have access to PlayerCash in other activities and want to make sure every time Player buy anything , the PlayerCash will change in MainActivity.

Comment: There are two options, 1- Pass the `PlayerCash` to second and third activity and if Player buy anything send it back to the previous activity with updated object. 2- Use database and update the information when User buy anything and when you go to the previous activity, query the database so that you get latest data.

Comment: Feel free to comment again if you will have any question. I have written article on how to pass objects between activities here: http://sumatodev.com/best-way-to-pass-data-between-android-activities-and-fragments/